# jQuery dataTables - Checking and adding new row if not exist using API .any()

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to add new row in datatables, and by using the API .any() to check if the id is already exist in the rows and if it exist I will not add new row to my datatable, and here is the result form my request from databse see http://pastie.org/10196001 , but I am having trouble in checking.

```js
socket.on('displayupdate',function(data){
     var dataarray = JSON.parse(data);
     dataarray.forEach(function(d){
         if ( table.row.DT_RowId(d.DT_RowId).any() ) { // TypeError: table.row.DT_RowId is not a function
            console.log('already exist cannot be added');
         }else{
            table.row.add(d).draw();
         }
     });
 });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The test data looks a little bit weird - it is a lot of chunks, i.e blocks of `[{..},{..}][{..},{..}][{..},{..}]` - I assume you are only processing one chunk or block at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error, of course, because `DT_RowId` not is a function in the API.  But [**`DT_RowId`**](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html) *is* in fact the one and only property that get some special treatment from dataTables :

> By assigning the ID you want to apply to each row using the property
>   DT_RowId of the data source object for each row, DataTables will
>   automatically add it for you.

So why not check `rows()` for that automatically injected `id` along with `any()`?

```js
socket.on('displayupdate',function(data){
   var DT_RowId,
       dataarray = JSON.parse(data); 
   dataarray.forEach(function(d){
       DT_RowId = d.DT_RowId;
       if (table.rows('[id='+DT_RowId+']').any()) {
          console.log('already exist cannot be added');
       } else {
          table.row.add(d).draw();
       }
   });
});
```

simplified demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f1yyuz1c/**

Comment: Thank you so much, I am almost close to your answer. :)

Comment: @jemz, Yes - your ingredients were right, just needed another recipe :) Thank you for accepting the answer.